# How to make 3rd party api call in dialogflow's inline editor

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

How to make 3rd party api call in dialogflow using inline editor please share if you have some code regarding this.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make external network requests (for example an API call) from the inline editor. You need to deploy your code elsewhere. The easiest way to do this is by deploying to a paid Firebase plan. [From Google](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/configure):

> Network calls originating from your Cloud Function for Firebase to destinations outside Google's network require billing to be enabled for the underlying Google Cloud or Firebase project.

Comment: This is not entirely true. The inline editor uses cloud functions under the hood. While, yes, you'll need to update your billing, external API calls will be accessible afterwards.

Comment: yes you are right. I forgot to check my billing section, now its work.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an API with the technology that you want, as long as the response from the API can be understand by Dialogflow.

You need to configure it by going to [Fulfillment](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/configure#custom_webhook), and point it to your API.

The API needs to respond with this structure: [Dialogflow](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/how-it-works#response_format).

And If you plan to integrate with Actions on Google, you have this [repository](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-json/tree/master/responses/v2/ActionsOnGoogle/RichResponses) which includes some examples of responses.

And [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#v2_client_libraries) you have some libraries to interact with Dialogflow with different languages.

Comment: If the answer is valid, mind if you set it as best answer? It helps me too