# DailogFlow API fulfillment to public endpoint gives Unauthorized 401

Tags: dialogflow-es, integration, webhooks, google-assist-api

I am new to this Dialog flow which I am using to try to connect my Google assistant with Salesforce based system.

Now, I have a public facing GET end point which I want to call from DialogAPI fulfillment

[image]

But it always fails with

> "webhookStatus": {
> "code": 16,
> "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAUTHENTICATED, State: URL_ERROR, Reason: ERROR_AUTHENTICATION, HTTP status code: 401."
> }

I cannot access the endpoint GET URL without any issues.
For reference, this is the endpoint -
https://assistant-check-developer-edition.eu44.force.com/assistant/services/apexrest/Dialogflow

which just returns a string.

Can someone please help me what I am missing here?

Thank you

Comment: Have you created your custom webhook code or you are using the inline editor of the Dialogflow? I think for the inline editor then you can not make it using the Dialogflow inline editor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53431544/how-to-make-3rd-party-api-call-in-dialogflows-inline-editor. (Note: Please have a look in the GCP logging for more info why it's showing the 401?)

Comment: Hi @DhruvRajkotia, I am not using the inline editor and directly adding the public endpoint. I added an image to the question

Comment: did this ever get fixed?

Answer (score 0):

From Google’s documentation:

> “If you plan to use the Dialog Flow API, you need to set up
> authentication. Any client application that uses the API must be
> authenticated and granted access to the requested resources.”

From the image you are sharing, you are missing an authorization method when you are trying to make the GET call. In [this](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#environment-service-accounts) link, you can read how to achieve a proper authorization method in your API.